# Using sqlalchemy.sql.functions.char_length as a filter condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I'm  using Elixir and sqla 0.6, and I'm trying to query my model:

```
class Document(Entity): 
    using_options(shortnames=True, order_by='doc_date')
    doc_number = Field(Unicode(20),index=True)
```

...for Documents having numbers of a given length.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
Document.query.filter(Document.doc_number.char_lenght()==5).all()
```

...but apparently, char_length, while present in sqlalchemy.sql.functions,  is not working here. How can I make it work within declarative idiom, without resorting to direct queries?

Comment: just a suggestioin: post your answer below, and accept it as the answer so people immediately will know that your problem is solved

Comment: @kusut I was trying to do what you suggested, but code markup didn't seem to work in the comment editor, and I got confused by the interface... I'll try again, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found an answer:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
Document.query.filter(func.char_length(Document.doc_number)==5).all()
```

Comment: I guess it's moved in a more recent version but it's now in `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.char_length`